# C# json deserialization itunes search api

Tags: c#, datacontract, deserialization, datamember

I just cant get this deserilization to work. It gives no error but artistName remains empty.

Can anyone help?

Json string:

{
 "resultCount":1,
 "results": [
{"wrapperType":"track", "kind":"song", "artistId":414401, "collectionId":6666512, "trackId":6666508, "artistName":"Autopilot Off", "collectionName":"Make a Sound", "trackName":"Byron Black", "collectionCensoredName":"Make a Sound", [...]"

HttpWebRequest webRequest;

```
    void StartWebRequest(string itunesUrl)
    {
        webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(itunesUrl); 
        webRequest.Method = "GET";
        webRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(FinishWebRequest), null);

    }

    void FinishWebRequest(IAsyncResult result)
    {

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(webRequest.EndGetResponse(result).GetResponseStream());
        string json = sr.ReadToEnd();

        Log.debugToVS("json: " + json);


        iTunesResult itunesObj = new iTunesResult();

        itunesObj = JSONHelper.Deserialise<iTunesResult>(json);

        Log.debugToVS("artistId: " + itunesObj.artistName);

    }

    public void iTunesSearch(string artist, string album, string title)
    {

        if(artist == "" && album == "" && title == "") return;

        string query = "http://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/wa/wsSearch?";

        query += "term=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(artist + " " + album + " " + title);

        query += "&media=music";
        query += "&limit=20";

        Log.debugToVS("url: " + query);

        StartWebRequest(query); 
    }

}

public class JSONHelper
{
    public static T Deserialise<T>(string json)
    {
        T obj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(json));

            DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(obj.GetType());
            obj = (T)serializer.ReadObject(ms); // <== Your missing line



            return obj;

    }
}

[DataContract]
public class iTunesResult
{
    [DataMember]
    public string artistName { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think there is a problem with your data contract. Looking at the Json the Data Contract should be something like this.

```
[DataContract]
public class iTunesResult
{
    [DataMember]
    public iTuneJsonResults[] results { get; set; }
}


[DataContract]
public class iTuneJsonResults
{
    [DataMember]
    public string artistName { get; set; }
}
```

and that line for Log.xxxx in FinishWebrequest should become:

```
foreach(var item in itunesObj.results)
     Log.debugToVS("artistId: " + item.artistName);
```